# how to get the item in listview when i use onItemClickListener

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, cursor

i want to get the item from listview. but when i try to click listview i got error.
can some body help me?

this my class activity.

```
data = new dbHelper(this);

    listKeluar = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listKeluar);

    String [] keluar = { data.k_nama, data.m_chiperteks, data.kel_waktu };
    int[] k = { R.id.tNama, R.id.tChiper, R.id.tWaktu };
    cursor = data.DataPesanKeluar();
    SimpleCursorAdapter keluarAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( this, R.layout.baris_keluar, cursor, keluar, k ); //this line my error
    listKeluar.setAdapter(keluarAdapter);
    listKeluar.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            if(cursor.moveToPosition(arg2)) {
                idkeluar = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data.kel_id));//my line error, if i delete this line my listview didn't respon when i click
                nama = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data.k_nama));
                chiperteks = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data.m_chiperteks));
                waktu = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data.kel_waktu));
            }

            Intent isiPesanKeluar = new Intent();
            isiPesanKeluar.setClass(KotakKeluar.this, IsiPesanKeluar.class);
            isiPesanKeluar.putExtra("idkeluar", idkeluar);
            isiPesanKeluar.putExtra("nama", nama);
            isiPesanKeluar.putExtra("chiperteks", chiperteks);
            isiPesanKeluar.putExtra("waktu", waktu);
```

this is my log cat

```
Java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
```

my method

```
public Cursor DataPesanKeluar() {
    Cursor c = dba.rawQuery(
            " SELECT "
            + kel_id + " AS _id,"
            + e_chiperteks + ","
            + k_nama + ","
            + kel_waktu +
            " FROM " + tbPesan + " INNER JOIN " + tbPesanKeluar +
            " ON "  + tbPesan + "." + p_idpesan + "=" + tbPesanKeluar + "." + kel_idpesan +
            " INNER JOIN " + tbEnkrip +
            " ON " + tbPesan + "." + p_idenkrip + "=" + tbEnkrip + "." + e_idenkrip +
            " INNER JOIN " + tbKontak + 
            " ON " + tbPesan + "." + p_idkontak + "=" + tbKontak + "." + k_id , null);
    return c;
}
```

my baris_keluar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tNama"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tChiper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tWaktu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

thank for helping me..
Regards..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
Cursor listCursor = (Cursor) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
        if(listCursor.moveToFirst())
```

Use

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(cursor.moveToPosition(arg2)) {
            idkeluar = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            nama = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data.k_nama));
            chiperteks = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data.m_chiperteks));
            waktu = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data.kel_waktu));
        }
```

Comment: i have try ur code but i got the same error, can u please help me :( i really need the solution ..

Comment: Did you change all your listCursor to cursor?

Comment: post DataPesanKeluar() method

Comment: i tried but my listview didn't respon when i click the list :(

Comment: So now there is no more error but the list does not respond on click?

Comment: Post your baris_keluar layout.

Comment: In your listview layout add android:choiceMode="singleChoice" to your ListView

Comment: I think you should post another question like "ListView onItemClickListener does not fired" and post the complete code for onItemClickListener and I will continue to try to help but you would get other people having this problem before that may help you better than I.

Comment: Did you call startActivity(isiPesanKeluar) after the line isiPesanKeluar.putExtra("waktu", waktu);?

Comment: thanks for ur answer, it's really useful. and i'm sorry if i unaccurate my code clearly :)

Comment: If your list still did not respond on click, put a log in onItemClick like Log.d("ActivityName", "onItemclick") and see if onItemClick being called. And post the question as I suggested. If nobody answer, leave a message here with the link to your post and I will take a look tomorrow as I get really late here and I am going to sleep.

Comment: You should unaccept my answer in your post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382416/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-not-exist as Yoann answer correctly a few second before my answer. An upvote is enough for me, I did upvote the Yoann answer after I wrote the answer and saw Yoann answer.

Comment: my list is working now, thanks to you :D
if i had error again i'll contact you :D

Comment: can u help me in my post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474958/my-sms-receiver-cant-accept-new-sms

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the item at position, using the a `CursorAdapter`, you can simple call `Adapter.getItemAtPosition(position)` casting the return object to `Cursor`. Afterwards you do not need to move it again. The returned value is what you have clicked:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
     Cursor tmpCursor = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
     // use the cursor to retrieve the content of the columns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    eventlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            TextView eventname = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"eventname is" + eventname.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```