# my sms receiver can't accept new sms

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

i want to receive sms on my application, but when i try to get new sms my application didn't get the new sms. I cannot find where I am doing wrong. I'm not sure if there's something wrong with the code, or debugging.

I'm trying to be notified if a new SMS arrives and save the sms on my database.

this is my receiver.

```
public void onReceive( Context c, Intent i) {
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] m = null;
    String s = "";
    TelephonyManager teleponyManager = (TelephonyManager) c.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int x;
    if (b != null) { //IF valid SMS
        Object[] p = (Object[]) b.get("p");
        m = new SmsMessage[p.length];
        for (x = 0; x < m.length; x++) { //FOR ambil konten SMS
            m[x] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])p[x]);
            s += "SMS dari " +m[x].getOriginatingAddress().toString().trim();
            s += " :";
            s += m[x].getMessageBody().toString();
            s += "\n";                              
        }
        Toast.makeText(c, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        nomor = m[x].getOriginatingAddress().toString().trim();
        pesan = m[x].getMessageBody().toString();

        Cursor cursorKontak = data.pilihKontak(nomor);
        if(cursorKontak.moveToFirst()) {
            idkontak = cursorKontak.getString(cursorKontak.getColumnIndex("idkontak"));
        }

        if(idkontak == null) {
            nama = nomor;
            data.inputKontak(nama, nomor);

            Cursor cursorKontak2 = data.pilihKontak(nomor);
            if(cursorKontak2.moveToFirst()) {
                idkontak = cursorKontak2.getString(cursorKontak2.getColumnIndex("idkontak"));
            }

            data.inputPesanMasuk(idkontak, pesan);      

        }else {
            data.inputPesanMasuk(idkontak, pesan);
        }

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("sms", s);
        c.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

my android manifest

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
package="com.sms" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="EnkripsiSMS" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".KotakMasuk"/>
    <activity android:name=".TulisPesan"/>
    <activity android:name=".KotakKeluar"/>
    <activity android:name=".HasilEnkripsi"/>
    <activity android:name=".KirimPesan"/>
    <activity android:name=".IsiPesanKeluar"/>
    <activity android:name=".DekripsiPesanKeluar"/>
    <activity android:name=".HasilDekripsiPesanKeluar"/>
    <activity android:name=".TeruskanPesanKeluar"/>
    <activity android:name=".KirimPesanKeluar"/>
    <activity android:name=".IsiPesanMasuk"/>
    <activity android:name=".DekripsiPesanMasuk"/>
    <activity android:name=".TeruskanPesanMasuk"/>
    <activity android:name=".HasilDekripsiPesanMasuk"/>
    <activity android:name=".Balas"/>
    <activity android:name=".HasilBalas"/>
    <activity android:name=".KirimPesanMasuk"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

can somebody help me?
i really need the solution.
thanks..

Comment: has your onReceive method been called?

Comment: how can i called the method? can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @androidDev Register the receiver in ur manifest....as the sms comes..ur receiver's OnRecieve will be called automatically

Comment: @user1969053 like this ??
    
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

Comment: @androidDev yes ...and then whenevr sms arrives ONRecieve call...Can u confirm whether ur onRecive is getting called or not

Comment: but i don't know my onReceive is getting called or not. can u explain to me how can i test my onReceive is getting called or not?

Comment: Add logging (use `android.util.Log`) to `onReceive()`, send your device an SMS, then attach your device to your PC and use DDMS or another tool to look at the logcat. All your log messages will be written there.

Comment: can u give me example to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `p` use `pdus`

```
Object[] p = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");
```

Comment: In your manifest move the </activity> in the main activity to the line above <receiver

Comment: if i do that, my app force closed and didn't get the new sms :(

Comment: The receiver tag has to be outside the activity tag. Just make them separated and if something wrong we can go from there.

Comment: Just change the so that the <receiver is outside the <activity and post the new manifest. If your app crash we go from there to find out why it crash.

Comment: You did change the p to pdus right? When you run what happen now.

Comment: Object[] pdus = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");
like that?
if i ran on my android, my app get forced closed and my new sms still on android message. not on my app.

Comment: I am not quite understand "my new sms still on android message. not on my app". Anyway post your logcat.

Comment: i ran my app on my android phone. when i sent sms to my number using my app, i didn't get the sms on my inbox on my app. my receiver didn't get the new sms. i think i don't have the logcat because i dont know how to use it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29817/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-androiddev)

Comment: you're right, i want to check on the database, if idkontak = null i want to save nomor on my db. but i got null value :(

Comment: What do you mean by you got null value? Go to chat

Comment: Yes, just go the chat when wait for me