# how to refresh the listView using the Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter

I have created a `ListView` using `CursorAdapter` . Now I am Trying to update the `ListView` and Refresh the value to the ListView .

But I am not able to figure out . How to work with `Loader` or `changeCursor()` to refresh my `ListView`

Below is My code of setting the `CursorAdapter` :

//SucessFully done here

```
SQLDataSore datastore = new SQLDataSore(PrintContent.this);

Cursor cursor                 = datastore.getJSONData();

final CursorDemo cursorDemo = new CursorDemo(PrintContent.this, cursor);

list_View.setAdapter(cursorDemo);
```

My `Button` `onClick` I am updating the Value into the Database
//SucessFully Done

```
btn_check.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view ) {

                String editTextValue = edit_check.getText().toString();

                if (editTextValue!=null) {


                    SQLDataSore sqlDataSore = new SQLDataSore(PrintContent.this);

                    Cursor cursor_update = sqlDataSore.updateData(editTextValue);

//Here How Should I update my ListView ...?
                }

            }
```

My UpdateData Method:

```
public Cursor updateData(String editContent){

        SQLiteDatabase updateContent = getReadableDatabase();


        Cursor cursor_update = updateContent.rawQuery( "update " +TABLE_NAME + " set content = '"+ editContent
                +"' "+" where _id = 357", null);

        return cursor_update;
    }
```

CursorDemo Class

```
public class CursorDemo extends CursorAdapter{

        public CursorDemo(Context context, Cursor c) {

            super(context, c , false);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.changeCursor(cursor);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView txt_content        = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
            TextView txt_likes_count    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_likescount);
            TextView txt_name         = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            TextView txt_display_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_display_name);

            txt_content.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content")));

        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context , Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_row_view, viewGroup ,false);

            return view;
        }

    }
```

Any Help is Appreciated...
            });

Comment: call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` worked only when adapter value changed either new value added or previously removed.In your case your cursor value is updated but adapter is not changed its value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If CursorDemo extends CursorAdapter, then you have to use `adapter.swapCursor(cursor_update);`

That should swap the old cursor out for the new one and reload the data. With `swapCursor`, the old cursor is not closed.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist ...althouh I have _id field in to my db table

Comment: @nitesh. '_id' is case sensitive. Make sure the column name is exactly the same.

Comment: @Sathesh Thks. I solved it long time before .It was not due to _id although.

Comment: @Gooziec Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor. Unlike changeCursor(Cursor), the returned old Cursor is NOT CLOSED.

Comment: That's correct answer! I faced this issue when I replace SimpleCurcorAdapter with CurcorAddapter and this solution is working.

Answer (score 4):

In your `CursorDemo` you have to owerwrite `changeCursor()` method and reset the `Cursor` if you have indexer you have to set it's cursor too.

```
@Override
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    mIndexer.setCursor(cursor);
    super.changeCursor(cursor);
}
```

> public void changeCursor (Cursor cursor)
>
> Added in API level 1 Change the underlying cursor to a new cursor. If
>   there is an existing cursor it will be closed.
>
> Parameters cursor The new cursor to be used

Also try for below method if it's apt for your requirement.

> *Set a `FilterQueryProviderand` pass your key to that `filter`.*

```
  final Cursor oldCursor = adapter.getCursor();
    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(myQueryProvider);
    adapter.getFilter().filter(editTextValue, new FilterListener() {
        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
            // assuming your activity manages the Cursor 
            // (which is a recommended way)
            stopManagingCursor(oldCursor);
            final Cursor newCursor = adapter.getCursor();
            startManagingCursor(newCursor);
            // safely close the oldCursor
            if (oldCursor != null && !oldCursor.isClosed()) {
                oldCursor.close();
            }
        }
    });

    private FilterQueryProvider myQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence searchKey) {
            // assuming you have your custom DBHelper instance 
            // ready to execute the DB request
            return sqlDataSore.updateData(searchKey);;
        }
    };
```

> **PS** : The Cursor must include a column named _id or this class will not work see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382416/caused-by-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-column-id-does-not-exist).

Comment: how this gonna refresh my listView and load my content from changed database the one I have UPdated...

Comment: any luck with adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: let me assume So you changed cursor then called notifyDataSetChanged() still your listview not get refreshed right?

Comment: I tried this way: Cursor cursor_update = datastore.updateData(editTextValue);

     final CursorDemo cursorDemo = new CursorDemo(PrintContent.this, cursor_update);

     cursorDemo.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: you may find this helpful please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937839/android-how-to-requery-a-cursor-to-refresh-listview-after-deleting-database-row)

Comment: according to above code you your listview does know about the new CusrorDemo that you have created try to set it with list view and try again. I recommend plz follow the link that I provided

Answer (score 1):

```
 btn_check.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view ) {

            String editTextValue = edit_check.getText().toString();

            if (editTextValue!=null) {


                SQLDataSore sqlDataSore = new SQLDataSore(PrintContent.this);

                Cursor cursor_update = sqlDataSore.updateData(editTextValue);

                 cursorDemo.swapCursor(cursor_update);
                 //or cursorDemo=new CursorDemo(this,cursor_update);

                  list_View.setAdapter(cursorDemo);
            }

        }
```

Put this on the activity where declare the ListView . Just create a new adapter and put it in new cursor then recreate it or swap the cursor. make sure your listview or adapter not constant.

Answer (score 0):

you could call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: sth evil would be `super.onCreate(null);`

Comment: Nope...java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist ...althouh I have _id field in to my db table –

Answer (score 0):

".java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist ...althouh I have _id field in to my db table" means that the value of "cursor" in your code is wrong.
Check the code of getting the value of "cursor" please. A cursor must have a column named '_id'。
This is my suggestion

Comment: thks I figured it out ...the Value was Correct but the need to move my cursor to postion first...My question is how would I refresh my ListView once I updated my Database from the Cursor

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to adapt/replace new cursor value to your list view , you should remove the old cursor from adapter and add new cursor value to the adapter.And finally adapt this adapter to listview using listview.setadapter(CursorAdapter) as follows. 

liveTagListCursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(
                        LiveTagProvider.TAG_LIST_URI, null, null, null, null);

    tagCursorAdapter = new LiveTagListCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                        liveTagListCursor);

    tagCursorAdapter.swapCursor(liveTagListCursor);

    listview.setAdapter(tagCursorAdapter);
```